# Trying to figure out bluebird way of doing promise flow

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to do promisification - and more specifically using bluebird. I've come up with some code that makes use of new Promises:

```
function createUser(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    User.createAsync(user)
        .then((doc) => {
            resolve(doc);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
  });
}

function create(data) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    User.findOneAsync({username: data.username})
        .then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                 resolve(`Username ${data.username} is already taken`);
            } else {
                createUser(data)
                    .then((user) => {
                        resolve(user);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
   })
}
```

But I feel like I'm not getting much out of bluebird this way and after browsing through the documentation it seems like this is something of an anti-pattern that should be avoided. How would I go about making for example this flow more bluebird style or better promisified in general?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto SimpleJ's answer, you can do the following with async functions to get even better code readability:

```
function createUser(data) {
  return User.createAsync(data);
}

// async functions!
//                     destructuring!
async function create({username}) {
  //                                   short literals!
  const user = await User.findOneAsync({username});
  if (user) { throw new Error(`Username ${username} is already taken`); }
  return createUser(data);
}
```

This gives you a very flat, almost synchronous looking code. Note the `await` before `User.findOneAsync()` for waiting on the Promise.

The code above is equivalent to the other answer's. Async functions require node 7.6 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

If `User.createAsync` and `User.findOneAsync` return promises, you don't need to wrap them in new promises. Just return the promises returned by your functions:

```
function createUser(data) {
  return User.createAsync(data);
}

function create(data) {
  return User.findOneAsync({username: data.username})
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        throw new Error(`Username ${data.username} is already taken`);
      } else {
        return createUser(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that this can be further improved with `async` functions, which are supported in the latest Node versions. You aren't using any Bluebird specific features here.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't quite get the point of promisifyAll until now. I guess you are right, I should probably look into the async/await structure instead.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That's not necessarily an improvement. It's just a different syntax for doing the same thing. I prefer a pure promise solution, as it's supported everywhere promises are available (which is anywhere if OP is using Bluebird).